# Oracle 10gr2: enforce dates entered are between 9am and 5pm?

Tags: oracle, date, time, constraints

I want to enforce that date-times that are entered fall between 9am and 5pm.  How do I enforce this with ORACLE CHECK constraints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create table date_check (
  2  dt date check( to_number( to_char( dt, 'HH24' ) ) between 9 and 16 )
  3* )
SQL> /

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1* insert into date_check values( to_date( '01/01/2008 08:30', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH2
4:MI' ) )
SQL> /
insert into date_check values( to_date( '01/01/2008 08:30', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'
 ) )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C006170) violated


SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1* insert into date_check values( to_date( '01/01/2008 10:30', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH2
4:MI' ) )
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1* insert into date_check values( to_date( '01/01/2008 17:30', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH2
4:MI' ) )
SQL> /

insert into date_check values( to_date( '01/01/2008 17:30', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'
 ) )
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C006170) violated
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Minor typo: "between 9 and 16" should read between "9 and 17" to match 9am-5pm.
Thanks.

Comment: I believe it should be between 9 and 16.  That allows times from 9:00:00 AM to 4:59:59 PM.  Between 9 and 17 allows times from 9:00:00 AM to 5:59:59 PM.  If you need to allow 5:00:00, you could add an an OR to_char(dt, 'HH24:MI:SS') = '17:00:00' to the constraint